# Why does adding content inside of a layout screw up the layout?

Tags: css

The following layout 2 column layout will get screwed up by adding the `<p>Hello</p>`... Can anyone give me a clue?

```
<div style="width:1280px; font-size:0;">
   <div style="width:640px; height:200px; background:blue; display:inline-block;">
      <p>Hello</p>
   </div>
   <div style="width:640px; height:200px; background:yellow; display:inline-block"></div>
</div>
```

I could see if the height of the "p" was actually larger than 200px, but it isn't.  So why doesn't it just go inside of its parent and stop messing with my layout?

To fix this, I ended up making the layout column divs relative, and using the absolute position on a child div that would be the container of the "p", but it seems like there is something obvious I am missing to make this situation simpler...

Comment: What's it supposed to look like and how is it "screwed up"?

Comment: Inline block items are vertically aligned as `baseline` by default. Add `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: I ran your example [with the "Hello"](http://jsfiddle.net/pL7smded/) and [without the "Hello"](http://jsfiddle.net/pL7smded/1/) and saw no difference in the layout.

Comment: @lurker Maybe you didn't see a difference because you didn't set the root div in the example to style="font-size:0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline block items are vertically aligned as baseline by default. Add `vertical-align:top`

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oczpfdnq/2/)

```
div {
    font-size:0; /* remove whitespace */
}

div div {
    font-size:1rem; /* reset font-size*/
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inline-block does leave some whitespace that is undesired most of the time do to spaces in your code. The best solution I think is to float it and use 50% for the width.

```
div {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background:blue;
```

}

the p tag will go in nicely.

example here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0688qgp3/1/)

other solutions and information here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/